# How to get test ERC20 tokens on mumbai testnet?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, defi

How I can get DAI, USDC, WETH, or any other erc20 token for mumbai testnet ?

I am working on lending and borrowing platform so I need test tokens for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can swap test matic with various erc20 tokens in quickswap itself.

Make sure to connect mumbai testnet when you are swapping.

I tested and it is working. Also you can find various testnet addresses [here](https://faucet.paradigm.xyz/).

https://quickswap.exchange/#/swap

You can find more information in these article by [quickswap](https://quickswap-layer2.medium.com/how-to-experiment-with-quickswap-on-the-mumbai-testnet-f90f0c2bfca7) itself.

Else, you can use this faucet to claim usdc directly.

[Filswan faucet](https://calibration-faucet.filswan.com/#/dashboard)

Tell me if it helps!

Comment: Thanks man for sharing useful links.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just making a platform, you can likely just make a test token (mint a new ERC20) and then use that.  The only change for the other ones should be changing the addresses then when you want to go live on mainnet.  Unless there's some specific reason you want to test those tokens (e.g. see how a liquidation affects DAI or something), you can probably just mock them

Comment: but for example normal eth token value is 1 ETH = $2000
my minted weth token will have no value it will be just one eth only not equal to $2000 .
and how i will calculate borrower interest rate like 
 user put 1 eth as collateral to our platform based value of 1 eth in $ we will allow borrower to borrow DAI/USDC  equal to 60%  of his eth value which will be $1200.
How i will calculate that value ?

Comment: that's an oracle.  The protocol doesn't know the value of 1 ETH unless you tell it.  For instance you'd want to use a system like Tellor or Chainlink to get the ETH/USD price from off-chain for calculating that value.  For testing...you just have pretend the test tokens have value.

Comment: thanks man i would use chainlink to get eth price now i got the idea thanks you very much.

Answer (score 0):

use https://www.buildbear.io/ With BuildBear you can create a private Testnet with a build faucet.

Comment: Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange! Please see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer  Your duplicate answers to other questions were flagged and will be deleted.  You must also disclose if you have affiliation to the website you are listing: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/promotion